# Sesame : how to remove the inference during queries?

Tags: sparql, ontology, sesame

I'm looking for a solution in order to "remove" the inference during a query launched on Sesame. I must use a "Native Java Store RDF Schema" repository and I have this query :
I have an instance, a NamedIndividual, and I want the uri of the class whose instance it is :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?uri WHERE  {   
        <http://www.semanticweb.org/ontotest#myInstance> rdf:type ?uri .
        FILTER (?uri rdf:type owl:Class)         
    }
```

The problem is that I get severals URI (whom the good URI) instead of one because of the inference. I get the superclasses of the ontology then there is no link with the class of the instance.
How to obtain the right result without change the repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [setIncludeInferred(false)](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/query/Operation.html#setIncludeInferred%28boolean%29) on your [Query](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/org/openrdf/query/Query.html) object before executing it through the API to avoid using inferred statements.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to return the most specific class(es) of which some individual is an instance.   [ThomasFrancart's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24616606/1281433)  explains how to disable inference, but you might not want to do that, because you might need inference to infer the most specific instance.  For instance, you might have a class hierarchy with the relationship

> SeniorCitizen ⊑ Person
>   Person ⊓ hasAge some integer[>= 60]  ⊑ SeniorCitizen

and the data:

> John rdf:type Person
>   John hasAge 62

Then if you disable inference, you won't be able to know that John is a SeniorCitizen, even though it's a more specific class than Person.  It sounds like you actually want to keep inference enabled, but to only return the most specific class(es).  You can do that with a query like this:

```
select ?class where {
  :myInstance rdf:type ?class .
  filter not exists { 
    ?subclass rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
    :myInstance rdf:type ?subclass .
    filter ( ?subclass != ?class )
  }
}
```

This says to find those values of `?class` such that `:myInstance` is an element of `?class`, but only where there's not `?subclass` that's a subclass of `?class` (other than `?class` itself) to which `:myInstance` also belongs.  Note that an instance can have multiple most specific classes though.

See:

- [retrieving most specific classes of instances](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19632992/1281433) (your question is almost a duplicate of this one)
- [How to get Least common subsumer in ontology using SPARQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23510851/1281433) (not the same question, but the answer uses a similar technique)

Comment: I didn't find the right query for my problem but the function setIncludeInferred run