# Obtain the most concret type according to DBpedia class hierarchy in N-Triples file

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia, n-triples, instancetype

I have a N-Triples file with entity types like this (sample):

```
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Volcán_Ichinski> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Location> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Volcán_Ichinski> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NaturalPlace> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Volcán_Ichinski> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Wayne_Watson> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Wayne_Watson> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Weston_(Texas)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Location> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Weston_(Texas)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Weston_(Texas)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Weston_(Texas)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Region> .
```

I want to obtain the most concrete type according to [DBpedia class hierarchy](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/) for each entity. Thus, each entity in the file will only have 1 DBpedia type.

In this case, result will be something like this (sample):

```
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Volcán_Ichinski> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/NaturalPlace> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Wayne_Watson> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
<http://es.dbpedia.org/resource/Weston_(Texas)> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Region> .
```

I don't know if this is possible, if not I will like to do something similar.
Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: based on your local dataset sample, you also have to download and load the DBpedia ontology (e.g. from [here](https://www.dbpedia.org/resources/ontology/)), which in fact contains the class hierarchy. The rest is pretty much straightforward and has been asked and answered several times here, e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632992/retrieving-most-specific-classes-of-instances

Comment: alternatively, you could also use a federated query against the public DBpedia endpoint, but I'd definitely go with the first option and load the schema locally to compute the most specific class(es)