# How to get the lowest subclass of an instances in an rdf graph?

Tags: sparql, subclass, ontology, superclass, rdflib

Imagine a ontology with several classes and subclasses. Now i use another namespace to instantiate for example a MathTeacher. MathTheacher is a subclass of Teacher and Teacher a subclass of Job.

Now i can easily query for all subclasses of the instance. But how to only return the lowest: MathTeacher?

Here the Ontology:

```
@prefix EX: <https://www.example.com#> .
@prefix jobOnt: <https://www.jobOnt.com#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

jobOnt:Job a rdfs:Class .

jobOnt:Teacher a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf jobOnt:Job .

jobOnt:MathTeacher a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf jobOnt:Teacher .

jobOnt:CalculusTeacher a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf jobOnt:MathTeacher .

jobOnt:OptimizationTeacher a rdfs:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf jobOnt:MathTeacher .

EX:Bob a jobOnt:MathTeacher .
```

Now i want to query for the Job type of Bob. The closest i get is:

```
    SELECT ?type
    WHERE {
    EX:Bob a ?type .
    ?type rdfs:subClassOf* jobOnt:Teacher . 
    }
```

This returns: https://www.jobOnt.com#Teacher and https://www.jobOnt.com#MathTeacher

But i only want to get Math Teacher because it is the lowest one in the class hirarch.

Comment: you can consider the task as *getting the most specific class(es) of an instance*, via SPARQL here we go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632992/retrieving-most-specific-classes-of-instances

Comment: If `MatchTeacher` also has sub-classes e.g. `CalculusTeacher` then by definition it wouldn't be the lowest subclass of an instances type.  Maybe you could clarify what you meant by that last sentence?

Comment: Imagine MathTeacher has a Subclass CalculusTeacher. And myns:Rob is a MathTeacher. The query should return MathTeacher, because it is the lowest subclass of Rob. It must not return Calculus teacher!

Comment: did you manage to create the query based on my link or do you still need help?

Comment: Honestly i still need help :/